# Listing multiple companies where ownership of the same gov contract (same job) on resume/linkedin?

Tags: resume, linkedin

Due to the weirdness that US government contracts can impose on people sometimes, I am now working for my third company this year to sit at the same desk and do the same job.

I started the year as a contractor, became an employee of one of the companies working on the project earlier in the year and at the end of the calendar year that company will be losing its role in the project so I have had to move to a different company to continue with the same "job".  It's still the same contract, **nothing else has changed**. (duties are the exact same)

Should this be presented on my resume/linkedin/whatever as three individual, relatively short, jobs with the same description but different companies, or somehow consolidated into a single job, which it is, but with all three companies listed?  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @gnat  I really don't think this is a duplicate.  The only answer to the referenced question talks about working for a company that was acquired by a different company and therefore had a name change.   This is not quite the same situation, its 3 separate, individual employers.

Comment: @gnat not a dupe, and the advice doesn't apply here as that addressed an acquisition, this is multiple contracts at the same place for different contracting companies.  Different animal.

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight have you read the duplicate question, there's nothing about acquisition there. And by the way the answer there reflects that, it only uses acquisition as an example of company change

Comment: @gnat read it, and this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @gnat That's exactly what I said, the only answer there references acquisition.   Since I am trying to get an answer, even if the question is roughly a duplicate, there isn't an answer there which applies to my situation.  People are very quick to yell "DUPLICATE" here.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @HerbWolfe  Thanks for pointing it out...I need time to digest that one.  It sounds like it might be related, but honestly that is so complicated I couldn't follow it.  His problem is way more complicated than mine.

Answer (score 3):

> Should this be presented on my resume/linkedin/whatever as three
>   individual, relatively short, jobs with the same description but
>   different companies, or somehow consolidated into a single job, which
>   it is, but with all three companies listed?

Simple.  **List this as one job**, and have the most **recent company** who won/owns the contract listed as your current employer.  If it ever becomes necessary, you can explain the situation to whomever asks.  ( prospective new employer, etc. )

Comment: I've had a similar situation with contract-to-hire before, but this is the first time I've gone from company to company and it feels a little different.  I'm somewhat concerned that, even though its one job, having three employers in under a year will be seen negatively and might not even get me to the point where I have the opportunity to explain it.

Comment: @bluegreen I felt the same way, which is why I did what I did.

Comment: Mister Postive (I can't seem to @ your name) Thanks.  I may take the approach you did.  It seems slightly deceptive, but it raises fewer red flags.

Comment: @bluegreen There is no need to use the @ when you are commenting on my answer, it notifies me automagically.

Comment: @bluegreen and by the way, the idea would be to get you an interview.  When you get the interview, you then explain the situation regarding working on the same government contract owned by multiple companies over the years.

Comment: You are 100% right.   The point is to get their attention.